# Toggle Hiding/Showing an Element

Tags: javascript, image, button, show-hide

I'm trying to have a couple of buttons to show and hide some pictures, I have gotten it to somewhat work, but when I start the webpage the pictures are already shown, when I try make them invisible at start. I have tried swapping the "block" and "none" sentences in the function, but it just made the button less responsive.

javascript part:

```
function bassnectar() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myDIV3");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

html part:

```
 <button onclick="bassnectar()">Bassnectar</button>
 <div id="myDIV3">
   <img src="/images/bassnectar.jpg">
 </div>
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: *"i try make them inviseble at start"* - If the default styling for your element(s) should be `display: none;` then you'd use CSS to define that.  (Or even just inline styling on the element(s).)

Answer (score 1):

What you’re missing is that you’re assuming that block elements have a default `display` value of `block`. Which would be intuitive.

Such is not the case though.

The initial value of `display` is the browser’s default. If you query the value of the `display` property on a new HTML element, you’ll get an empty string.

It doesn’t return `block` until you explicitly set its `display` to `block`.

***Edit:***

It's important to note that ***setting a value in CSS doesn't change the behavior***. If you set a div to be display block in CSS, it will still return an empty string if you query it.

Here's a working example:

```js
var block = document.createElement("div");
var inline = document.createElement("span");

console.log("Initial display values:")
console.log(`block.style.display: ${block.style.display}`);
console.log(`inline.style.display: ${inline.style.display}`);

block.style.display = "block";
inline.style.display = "inline";

console.log("\nAfter setting them explicitly:")
console.log(`block.style.display: ${block.style.display}`);
console.log(`inline.style.display: ${inline.style.display}`);
```

```css
div {
  display: block !important;
}
```